# « Réaliser » vs « se rendre compte »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes

> Le soldat a réalisé avoir trop parlé.
>
> Le soldat s'est rendu compte qu'il avait trop parlé.

Y a-t-il une différence entre les deux phrases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L’une des définitions présentées par le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9aliser) nous indique qu’ils sont synonymes, mais que *réaliser* en ce sens est un tour qui fut vivement critiqué, et l’est encore de nos jours, quoique dans un moindre degré :

> **RÉALISER**   Prendre conscience d'une situation, d'un fait. **Synon. *se rendre compte*, *s'apercevoir***. *Réaliser la gravité du problème.* *J'ai soudain réalisé la situation, prévu que Folcoche, sans paraître ridicule, ne pouvait organiser le siège de son propre fils dans sa propre maison* (H. Bazin, Vipère,1948, p. 201)
>
> **Rem.** Cette acception s'est répandue dans les milieux mondains et cultivés ainsi que dans la langue littéraire dans le 1<sup>er</sup> quart du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Elle a suscité, jusque dans les années cinquante, de vives réactions chez les puristes qui y voyaient l'une des manifestations de la contamination du français par l'anglais. Aujourd’hui encore, cet emploi est parfois qualifié de *familier* ou *populaire*.

On note dans *Le Petit Robert* que le tour est critiqué, bien que le dictionnaire lui-même ne prenne pas position à ce sujet.

Dans la vie francophone contemporaine, les deux sont communément utilisés, et peu se formalisent d’une possible ascendance anglaise.

Answer (score 2):

Le sens est très proche.. Je dirais qu'avec "réaliser" on sous-entend un processus de réflexion plus long.