# What's the difference between «réaliser» and «se rendre compte» in this context?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I've been told that if I want to say "I only realised that after something happened" I would say «J'ai réalisé ça seulement après quelque chose est arrivé". Is there any difference here if I use «se rendre compte» instead of «réaliser» c'est-à-dire «Je m'en suis rendu compte seulement après quelque chose est arrivé»?

Comment: And https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31304/358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Réaliser* and *se rendre compte* are synonymous here. For a while, the former [was criticized for being an anglicism](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5262) (when is has this meaning) but it's not an issue anymore. There might still be an ambiguity if the context doesn't make clear what meaning of *réaliser*<sup>1</sup> is expected though.

I would rephrase your sentences that way:

> *Je l'ai réalisé seulement après que quelque chose soit<sup>2</sup> arrivé*

> *Je m'en suis rendu compte seulement après que quelque chose soit<sup>2</sup> arrivé*

or with a *ne ... que* form:

> *Je ne l'ai réalisé qu'après que quelque chose soit<sup>2</sup> arrivé*

> *Je ne m'en suis rendu compte qu'après que quelque chose soit<sup>2</sup> arrivé*

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>For a description of the different meanings of *réaliser*, see https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9aliser</sub>
<sup>2</sup>  <sub>Many prescriptive grammars tells the indicative must be used here (*[...] après que quelque chose **est** arrivé*). However, the subjunctive is leading in actual usage and the indicative is often perceived to be a mistake.</sub>